# Can not use Vs Code debugger. Unable to read source map of https://.... of self signed certificate in debug console VS Code

Tags: reactjs, ssl, visual-studio-code

Recently I had to edit my react project .env file and used HTTPS=true in order to make my localhost run in https. I am unable to use vscode debug ever since.The vs code debug console gives me the following error
"Could not read source map for https://.... of self signed certificate"

This is my launch.json configuration

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch Edge",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "pwa-msedge",
      "url": "https://dev-local.com:4200",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },
    {
      "type": "pwa-chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Chrome",
      "url": "https://dev-local.com:4200",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am unable to use VS Code debugger anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by adding "http.proxyStrictSSL": false
to my settings.json file

Comment: I have this issue with the error message "Could not read source map for https://<...>.net:4200/styles.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://<...>.net:4200/styles.js.map: self signed certificate" and I tried this but the issue still persisted with the same error message.